# in plsql, i saw some one use for loop without define the loop index, why? how?

Tags: plsql, loops, for-loop

in plsql, i saw some one use for loop without define the loop index, and the database can execute correctly. but i can't find the description of this syntax in oracle documentation. can anyone explain it? great thanks!

the following code is an example, notice the ***inner_c*** is not defined:

```
declare
    v_current_nr NUMBER;
begin
    v_current_nr:=0;

    loop
        for inner_c in 1..4
        loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_current_nr);
        end loop;

        v_current_nr:=v_current_nr+5;
        exit when v_current_nr>25;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You asked for docs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#sthref945

Comment: More technical specification: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/loop_statement.htm#i34785

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inner_c is being used as the handle/variable for the loop.  If you DBMS_OUTPUTed it, you'd see that it looped through the numbers 1 - 4 in this case.

It's implicitly declared as part of the loop mechanism.  It will fall out of scope when the loop is over.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "the loop index"?

You can have: `For i in 1..5`
which gives i the values of 1 through 5

But you can also have:

```
For record in myCursor Loop
  record.myField
End Loop
```

Which will return each time a row of the cursor.
Maybe you can give an example of what you saw?

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php